# How to convert r data frame to h2o object

Tags: r, dataframe, h2o

Im new to R and H2O and I have tried to find a way to convert r data frame to a h2o object. I have spent some time research on how to do this with no luck. Other way around is possible and well documented as follows.

```
prosPath = system.file("extdata", "prostate.csv", package="h2o")
prostate.hex = h2o.importFile(localH2O, path = prosPath)
prostate.data.frame <- as.data.frame(prostate.hex)
```

But what i want is complete opposite of this. I wants to convert r "prostate.data.frame" data object converted to h2o object named "prostate.hex".
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please try this:

```
prostate.hex <- as.h2o(localH2O, prostate.data.frame, key="prostate.hex")
```

Comment: This is now quite out of date (since h2o version 3). See also: [Unable to convert data frame to h2o object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442820/unable-to-convert-data-frame-to-h2o-object)

Comment: The answer by @Ram is the easier/simpler one.

Answer (score 35):

As per h2o version 3.6.0.8, it does not require any parameters. Example:

```
iris.hex <- as.h2o(iris)
```

Comment: Why do we append a .hex?

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is out of date at this point (Jan-22-2016), so here's what works at present day

```
prostate.hex <- as.h2o(prostate.data.frame, destination_frame="prostate.hex")
```